# OpenCV blob detection segfaults when filtering by color

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm having trouble using the filterByColor functionality in the SimpleBlobDetector tool that ships with OpenCV. Make doesn't give me any errors, but when I try to run the program, it segfaults at blobme.detect().

It works fine when I use filterByArea, it's just filterByColor that's giving me headaches.

```
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define ACTIVE_CHANNEL 2

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    std::cout << "./image_proc <file> <thresh> (-1 for default)" <<    std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  cv::Mat test_im = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cv::Mat hsvim, outim, channels[3], descriptor;
  std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;

  // Convert to HSV
  cv::cvtColor(test_im, hsvim, CV_RGB2HSV); 
  cv::split(hsvim, channels);

  cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
  params.filterByInertia = false;
  params.filterByConvexity = false;
  params.filterByColor = true;
  params.filterByCircularity = false;
  params.filterByArea = false;
  params.blobColor = 255;
  //params.minArea = 100.0f;
  //params.maxArea = 500.0f;

  // Trying to use blob detector
  cv::SimpleBlobDetector blobme(params);

  blobme.detect(channels[ACTIVE_CHANNEL], keypoints);

  // Print keypoints
  cv::drawKeypoints(channels[ACTIVE_CHANNEL], keypoints, outim);

  // Display
  cv::namedWindow("Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imwrite("imout.jpg", outim);
  cv::imshow("Display window", outim);

  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works fine with a simple binary image. However for a more complex image, the program may crash simply because `SimpleBlobDetector::detect` cannot handle it. Try to eanble more filters and tune params.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is because of the image size. I've tested with a small grayscale image but `SimpleBlobDetector::detect` still crashes.

Comment: Strangely enough, it works with the original sized image when I set both `filterByColor` and `filterByArea` to true. And the result I get is not the same as solely filtering by area. Huh...